# How to read a binary file and save it inside a pipe

Tags: c, io, pipe, fread

I used the code below to open a binary file `fp` (the file contain a saved 2D array) and put it inside a pipe:

```
if ((fp=fopen("file", "rb"))==NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open file.\n");
}
if (fread(array, sizeof(int), 5*5, fp) != 5*5) {
    if (feof(fp))
        printf("Premature end of file.");
} else {
    printf("File read error fread.");
}
```

Is this the code to put it inside the pipe?

```
close(fd[0]);
if ((ch=fgetc(fp))==EOF)
    write(fd[1], &ch, 1 );
```

If I want to make a sum of the array, how could I make it?

Comment: You're still calling fread when the file open fails. You should return after error messages.

Comment: @phihag- no error message in this code

Comment: @Bobj-C then what is the message in the second line? Looks like an error message to me. Anyway, you call fread with fp even if fp is NULL, don't you?

Comment: the second message i dont know if it right because this i asked

Comment: @Bobj-C: No, you didn't ask about that part of the code (i.e., the message on the second line, not the second message!), you asked how to pipe the data and how to sum the array (what does the array hold?). @phihag is trying to point out that you are checking for a failed open and reporting it, but then continuing to use the file-descriptor anyway.

Comment: the array hold integers array[10][2]

Comment: If your array is 10x2, it has 20 elements; reading 25 (5x5) elements into the array is going to wreak havoc on your data space.

Comment: @Bobj-C: Your `fread` usage is bad: it will output `File read error fread` on success. Try simpler code: `if (fread(array, sizeof(int), 5*5, fp) != 5*5) {printf("File read error fread.");}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most sensible way to write the array to the pipe, as long as the size remains small, is to do:

```
int nw = 5 * 5 * sizeof(int);
if (write(fd[1], array, nw) != nw)
    err_exit("Failed to write to pipe");
```

(Where `err_exit()` is a function that writes a message to standard error and exits (or does not return.)

This assumes that your array is a 5x5 array (a comment from you implies it is 10x2, in which case your reading code has major problems).  It assumes that the size of the buffer in a pipe is big enough to hold the data; if it is not, your write call may block.  It assumes that there is somewhere a process to read from the pipe; if this is the only process, the `write()` will trigger a SIGPIPE signal, killing your process, because of the `close(fd[0]);`.

Writing one byte at a time is possible - it is not stellar for performance.

Reading one byte at a time from `fp` after you've already read the data into `array` is not entirely sensible - you are at best reading different data for writing to the pipe.

The normal way of summing a 2D array is (C99):

```
enum { DIM_1 = 5, DIM_2 = 5 };
int array[DIM_1][DIM_2];

...data to load array...

int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < DIM_1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < DIM_2; j++)
         sum += array[i][j];
}
```

It doesn't matter where the data came from, just so long as you actually initialized it.